# Existence of a vector bundle over a curve with certain property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces

Is there a curve (compact Riemann surface) $X$, a (holomorphic) vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$ over $X$, and an integer $d>0$ such that the following hold?

- There are surjections $\rho : \mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}$, $\rho ':\mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathcal{L}'$ where $\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L}'$ are line bundles of the same degree $-d$, yet $\mathcal{L} \ncong \mathcal{L}'$.
- $\text{ker}(\rho)$ and $\text{ker}(\rho')$ are line bundles of degree $>-d$.

Comment: This can not happen. What have you tried?

Comment: @Mohan I only dealt with the case of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: How did you do it for projective line? Have you tried extending the argument?

Comment: @Mohan For the projective line the line bundles are classified by degree, so the first bullet point is impossible. But more generally, I figured it out for split $\mathcal{E}$, by using that if $L_1 \rightarrow L_2$ is a nonzero morphism of line bundles, then $\text{deg}(L_1) < \text{deg}(L_2)$. I'm still not sure about the case when $\mathcal{E}$ is indecomposable.

Comment: (above, my $<$ should be a $\leq$)

Comment: @Mohan, Ok, I figured out that case too using similar reasoning. Thanks for your prodding.